# Command not found: create-lwc-app

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've been trying to install LwC locally via nodeJS based on the instructions given [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/install) however I get the following error :

> $ npx create-lwc-app demo-Lwc npx: installed 1 in 7.837s command not
>   found: create-lwc-app

I've pulled the necessary code from GitHub and saved it within the subfolder where i'm executing the bash command above.

I also added npm folder to my system environment path variables

- C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

This is probably a simple explanation --- hoping someone can point me in the right direction

System info :

- Win 10
- $ npx -v = 6.11.3
- $ npm -v = 6.11.3
- $ node -v = v6.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `lwc-create-app`.

you have `create` first not `lwc`.

Should work if you change the order

Comment: oooh boy --- that was simple (should have seen that--- the readme documentation is incorrect BTW)--- thank u Brett